# brainf*ck interpreter in c - handling bracket loops

Tags: c, brainfuck, putchar

I'm writing a brainfuck interpreter in C.

<del>The bracket (`[]`) loops aren't seeming to work properly.</del>

EDIT: this code is now working

This is the code controlling the bracket loops:

```
  case '[': // start bracket loop
    if(!*(cells + i))
    {
      bracket++;
      while(bracket)
      {
        n++;
        if(bf[n] == ']')
          bracket--;
        else if(bf[n] == '[')
          bracket++;
      }
    }
    break;
  case ']': // end bracket loop
    if(*(cells + i))
    {
      bracket++;
      while(bracket)
      {
        n--;
        if(bf[n] == '[')
          bracket--;
        else if(bf[n] == ']')
          bracket++;
      }
    }
    break;
```

The program is reading from a string containing the bf code. For each character, the appropriate section of a switch statement (with cases for each command) is called.

When a ']' command is called, the program <del>won't</del> returns to the beginning of the loop.

Thanks for any help!

<del>EDIT: I updated to show what has been exposed to be an actual problem, after fixing some bugs pointed out below.</del> I'm using the gdb debugger on Ubuntu 14.04.

EDIT (again): The program is now working and is available below.

EDIT (again(again)): As I said in a comment below, in the end there were a variety of bugs causing problems, so I didn't have a single answer to answer my own question with. I left this up as an example of one way to handle bracket loops if anyone was interested.

The entirety of the code can be viewed on GitHub at https://github.com/underscorejho/bfi

Comment: `if (cells + i + 1)` in the linked code is wrong. You probably meant something like `if (i < size - 1)`. Also, instead of doing `*(cells + i)`, just do `cells[i]`. Those are the same. (They're even *defined* to be the same.)

Comment: did you step through with a debugger?

Comment: So `if (cells + i + 1)` won't check if the next one has been initialized because... it's not always going to be null? correct?

Comment: `if (cells + i + 1)`is likely to always be true in practice (it's the same as `if (cells + i + 1 != 0)`), so the result is that the `cells` array is never grown nor the new elements zero-initialized. You might get some garbage values.

Comment: undefined behavior is present in your program

Comment: could you elaborate?

Comment: If your problem has been fixed, why don't you answer your own question, so people coming here in the future can get help, too?

Comment: There were a variety of bugs that together caused the issues. There wasn't a clear single answer to post. I left it up as an example of one way to handle bracket loops.